# A natural number $n>2$ is a prime iff $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv n-1 \pmod {\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, congruences

Is this proof acceptable ?

> **Theorem 1** (Wilson)**.** A natural number $n>1$ is a prime iff:
>    $$(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod n.$$

> **Theorem 2.** A natural number $n>2$  is a prime iff:
>   $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv n-1 \pmod {\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k}.$$

**Proof**

Necessity: *If $n$ is a prime, then*
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv n-1 \pmod {\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k}.$$
If $n$ is an odd prime, then by Theorem $1$ we have 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv n-1 \pmod n$$ 
Hence, $n \mid ((n-1)!-(n-1))$ and therefore $n \mid(n-1)((n-2)!-1)$.

Since $ n \not\mid (n-1)$ it follows $n \mid ((n-2)!-1)$ , hence 
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \mid (n-1)((n-2)!-1),$$
thus 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv n-1 \pmod {\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k}.$$

Sufficiency: *If*
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv n-1 \pmod {\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k}$$
*then $n$ is a prime.*

Suppose $n$ is a composite and $p$ is a prime such that $p \mid n$, then since $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ it follows $p \mid \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k$ .

Since
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv n-1 \pmod {\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k},$$ we have $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv n-1 \pmod {p}.$$

However , since $p \leq n-1$ it divides $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k$, and so 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} k \equiv 0 \pmod p,$$
a contradiction . Hence $n$ must be prime.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Does Theorem 2 hold for $n=6$?

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment! It seems that the proof is ok.

Comment: @JankoBracic it's ok ...hvala :)

Comment: It is not true that for every prime $p \mid n$ we have $p \mid \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. It's a minor incovenience since the statement is false iff $p=2$ and $n=2 m$ where $m$ is odd. You can fix the proof by taking a different $p$ in that case.

Comment: GUI application that implements this test can be found [here](https://github.com/PedjaTerzic/Wilson) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After "thus" I had to backtrack because I didn't realize that $(n-1)! - (n-1)$ and $ (n-1) \cdot ((n-2)!-1)$ are the same number, you only said that they are both divisible by $n$ but the conclusion doesn't follow from that alone; also you ought to point out that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k}=\frac{n \cdot (n-1)}{2}$ here instead of later.

Also it would be a bit simpler to replace $n-1$ with $n$ everywhere, it would make the summation identity more recognizable too so maybe you don't even need to mention it at all.

Aside from those minor quibbles, it is clear and convincing!

Answer (score 0):

"Suppose $n$ is a composite and $p$ is a prime such that $p \mid n$, then since $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ it follows $p \mid \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k$."

This only follows if $p$ is an odd prime (consider $p=2, n=6$). It's easy to dismiss the other options, but this should explicitly be part of the proof.